# How to run two python event loops and share the same memory?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, multiprocessing, twisted

I am using twisted and PySide2 to create an app that can send information through network. However, `twisted's reactor` and `PySide2's QApplication` both need an event loop that runs forever.

What I need is when twisted receives a new message, I want it to update the message in the PySide2 Window. So that means **twisted and PySide2 need to share the same memory.**
Here's some sample code:

```py
def dataReceived(self, data): # a function inside a twisted class
    QLabel.setText(data.decode()) # a pyside2 object
```

I cannot use threading, because twisted and PySide2 **both needed to be in the main thread**; And multiprocessing **can't share memory like QWidget objects.**

So how can I run these two event loops at the same time, and let them share the same memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the Twisted and Qt5 event loops side-by-side using https://pypi.org/project/qt5reactor/.